# How do I retrieve an image from a database in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, varbinary

I have been working on a system to allow our users to upload images into the database.  Uploading the image to the database seems to work fine but I can't seem to get the image back out and to display in my view.  I don't get any error messages the image simply doesn't show.  Here is my code so far.

**Controller** / Create Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(UserAccount userAccount, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var photo = new UserImage
                    {
                        FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                        FileType = FileType.VesselImage,
                        ContentType = upload.ContentType
                    };
                    using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                    {
                        photo.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                    }
                    userAccount.UserImages = new List<UserImage> { photo };
                }
                db.UserAccounts.Add(userAccount);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }//if
        }//try
        catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */) 
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(userAccount);
    }
```

**Controller** / Details Method
*Breakpoints show that the image is found and selected at this stage.*

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        UserAccount userAccount = db.UserAccounts
            .Include(s => s.UserImages)
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.userId == id);
        if (userAccount == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(userAccount);
    }
```

**View** / Details

```
@model Multiple_Table_Post.Models.UserAccount
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
<div>
<h4>UserAccount</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userName)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.userName)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userLocation)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.userLocation)
    </dd>


    @if (Model.UserImages.Any(f => f.FileType == FileType.VesselImage))
    {
        <dt>
            Image
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <img src="~/File?id=@Model.UserImages.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.VesselImage).FileId" alt="avatar" />
        </dd>
    }

</dl>
</div>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.userId }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

I think that something is wrong with my condition:

```
@if (Model.UserImages.Any(f => f.FileType == FileType.VesselImage))
    {
        <dt>
            Image
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <img src="~/File?id=@Model.UserImages.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.VesselImage).FileId" alt="avatar" />
        </dd>
    }
```

If I break at this point within the view I can see that the image is selected but noting is ever output.  I just returns nothing.

I have included my models too in the hope I can get to the bottom of this problem.  Here they are:

**Model** / UserAccount

```
namespace Multiple_Table_Post.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class UserAccount
{        

    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string userLocation { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<UserImage> UserImages { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Model** / UserImage
    namespace Multiple_Table_Post.Models
    {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public partial class UserImage
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PersonId { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }

    public virtual UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Model** / FileType

```
namespace Multiple_Table_Post.Models
{
public enum FileType
{
    VesselImage = 1, Photo
}
}
```

Thanks, If I've missed anything that would make this easier please let me know.

Update: Here I have included the breakpoint information about what the system is doing when the condition is hit and the data is can see.

[image: Condition is reached and the system knows there is an image in there]
[image]

Comment: I usually use `<img src="@Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.ImageLink).ToHtmlString()" />` (as I store the image path in the db)

Comment: Could you show code behind this `~/File?id=...` call? Maybe this method returns incorrect `Content-Type` header?

Answer (score 1):

The way I prefer to do this is to create an ActionResult that directly services browser requests for an image.  One of the advantages of this approach is if the page includes the image more than once, the browser will automatically share the resource.  This saves database hits, data transfer and maximises caching opportunities.

```
public ActionResult Portrait(int id)
{
    vPhotos p = sdb.vPhotos.Where(e => e.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
    byte[] photoArray = new byte[] { };
    return File(smallPhotoArray, "image/png");
}
```

Now in your view, simply call the ActionMethod as a img src reference:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Portrait", "MyController" , new { id = id })" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,[byte array]"/>
```

Replace:

1. `jpg` with the type of image i.e. `FileType`
2. `[byte array]` with your byte array i.e. `Content`.

You need to convert `Content` to `base64` if it isn't already.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have been playing around a little more and noticed something in the update that I posted.  In the following image:
[image]
You'll notice that the FileType is listed as 0, however in the FileType class I have told it that the FileType is 1.

```
public enum FileType
{
    VesselImage = 1, Photo
}
```

So the condition is not met as it cannot see a FileType that is equal to 0. Changing the VesselImage to 0 in my FileType class resolves the problem. :)